# In $\Bbb R^3$, If tangent map of F preserves inner product, then F is an isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry, diffeomorphism

I am differential geometry beginner. I have one question.

Following statement is well known.
If $F$  : $\Bbb R^m\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ is a map & diffeomorphism. And if $F_*$(tangent map of $F$) preserves inner product, then $F$ is an isometry.

But In $m=n=3$, $F$ is still Isometry even if we subtract the condition of '$F$ is a diffeomorphism'

I tried several ways to prove this, but it was useless. I really want to know this elementary proof. Thanks.

Comment: But...That article is about to when F is a diffeomorphism. I am curious when the diffeomorphism condition is missing in $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: Am missing something, or the fact that we are dealing with a diffeomorphism is actually *not* in the answer to that other question?

Comment: what do you mean " actually not in the answer to that other question"?

Comment: I mean that the answer doesn't use that hypothesis.

Comment: I see. But I think that answer is incorrect. In general, I know that diffeomorphism condition is esscential to this proposition.

Comment: The answer does use that hypothesis: smoothness to see that $dF$ makes sense, and that $dF$ preserves inner product implies that it is an isomorphism, hence by inverse function theorem $F$ is a diffeomorphism. In fact it's unclear how to state your hypotheses ("$F_*$ preserves inner product") unless $F$ is a diffeomorphism by the same argument.

Comment: @MikeMiller you say that $F_*$ preserves inner product if and only if $F$ is  diffeomorphism by inverse funtion theorem. So for any m,n (not even specially m=n=3), if $F_*$ preserves inner product, then condition for diffeomorphism of $F$ is automatically established?

Comment: I say that *if* $F_*$ preserves inner product, then $F_*$ is an isomorphism (or an injection of vector spaces), and hence $F$ is a local diffeomorphism (or immersion). (Of course the converse is false.) I guess this assumes that $F$ is $C^1$ (or else there is no inverse function theorem). I don't know any theorems about isometries between Euclidean spaces that are very special to $m,n = 3$. Perhaps there are some in low regularity ($C^0$ functions which still have well-defined derivatives?), but I don't know and am slightly skeptical.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks a lot !!